# What are the required permissions to execute firebase auth:export command?

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebase-cli

I tried `firebase auth:export` command with a manually created service account, but got the following error:

```
bash-5.1# firebase auth:export accounts.json --project=my-project
Exporting accounts to accounts.json

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

I assume this is because the service account doesn't have required permissions for the export operation, but I'm not sure what permissions are required since the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#auth-export) doesn't really explain that part.

Comment: Did you try creating service account using [firebase console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup?authuser=0)? If the service account created using Firebase works for export, then is it possible for you to check the permissions assigned to the Firebase service account and compare them to your custom service account?

Comment: @RajeevTirumalasetty As it turned out, it was firebaseauth.viewer that was missing.

Answer (score 3):

Solved it by assigning `firebaseauth.viewer` role to the servicve account.

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding my-project \
    --member serviceAccount:my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --role roles/firebaseauth.viewer
```

Roles reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles-predefined-product#auth